# Convert bat to exe programmatically

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

How can I convert .bat file to .exe programmatically?
 Please, not via iexpress.
I need the exe file to execute the script itself, and not delegate cmd

Comment: So, define programmatically plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use 'Bat to Exe Converter'. I couldn't find a link I trust anymore but these types of programs are not far and few. It seems to do the job for me, I can give the program a version number, an icon, force it to run as Admin, Delete on exit, encrypt, 32 or 64 bit, make it invisible, include other files into the .exe for it to unzip. Again, there are many programs like this.

Comment: I tried this [link](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bat_to_exe_converter.html). It has CLI and works fine, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Batch files are a series of instructions sent through the command interpreter. Even "converted" to an EXE a batch file will always require the command interpreter.

Comment: I mean, to interpret the script to assembly instructions for exe file.

Comment: That's not what you asked. Please make your questions what they are actually about. We can only answer the questions that are asked, and cannot guess what you really mean.

Comment: Further, the majority of "Bat to EXE" programs do not do this. They simply wrap the script in other code that hides the visible command windows, if possible.

Answer (score -2):

Abyssmedia claims a real compilation in its Quick Batch File Compiler https://www.abyssmedia.com/quickbfc/

I tried to compile a simple script with text output and did not notice any calls to cmd.exe